# Как можно остановить выполнение функции при исчезновении из поля видимости?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

То есть если мы проскроллили ниже этого блока то функция отключается, если вернулись опять на эту секцию то включили?

```
    let num = 0;
const max = $('.technology-timeline-tab').length;
let autoplayTimer; // переменная для id
function autoplay() {
    $('.technology-timeline-tab').each(function (id) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            // eslint-disable-next-line radix
            num = parseInt(id) + 1;
        }
    });
    if (num >= max) {
        num = 0; // Или обнуляем или останавливаем: return false;
    }
    $('.technology-timeline-tab').removeClass('active');
    $('.technology-timeline-tab').eq(num).trigger('click');
    autoplayTimer = setTimeout(autoplay, 5000); // сохранили
}
setTimeout(autoplay, 5000);

$('.technology-timeline-content__section').mousedown(function () {
    $(this).addClass('mousedown');
    $('.technology-timeline-content__section').css('cursor', 'grabbing');
    clearTimeout(autoplayTimer); // остановили
});

$(window).mouseup(function () {
    if ($('.technology-timeline-content__section').hasClass('mousedown')) {
        $('.technology-timeline-content__section').removeClass('mousedown');
        $('.technology-timeline-content__section').css('cursor', 'grab');
        autoplay(); // запустили
    }
});
```

Comment: [Вот это](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) должно помочь. Кратко если, то апишка отслеживает положение определённого блока относительно экрана.